# FocusLost called after menuaction

Tags: java, swing

I have a MenuItem with a shortcut key to save the data of a JTextFied temporary and print it

The save function is called on FocusLost event of the JTextField and the print is called via MenuItems actionListener and is fired when I click on the MenuItem as well as when i press the shortcut key for the menuitem (eg: f1)

The problem is that when i directly press f1(shortcut for menuitem), the focusLost event for the Textfied is fired only after the menuitem has performed its action, whereas when I go to the menu and press, the focuslost is fired first followed by the menu's Action

Is there a way to force a Focuslost so that even with a shortcut key, the focusLost event is fired first

Tried using requesfocusinWindow, setText (performed on other demo textfields just to force a focusLost)

Comment: sounds like your setup is wrong somehow - time for an sscce to see exactly what you are doing

Answer (score 2):

1) I think that's not possible in Programing Languages, more about that in the theory of [AWT Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/FocusSpec.html) and [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html),

2) you have to redirect this Save Processes to the Backgroung Task, and before that you can check if `JMenu` and its `JMenuItem` are/aren't selected, for this check use only `ButtonModel`, otherwise don't do that, because your GUI heve to waiting for this processes

3) anothere choice is save on periodical bases values from `JComponents` to some `Array`, there you can check if value was/were changed, all changes must be checked/saved from Backgroung Task, without any impact to the Swing GUI

4) easiest way how to create something as Timer would be to wrap some logics to the `Runnable#Thread`, delayed by `Thread.sleep(int)` but exclusively inside `Runnable#Thread` only

Answer (score 1):

It is generally suspect when you want to 'force' focusLost, as the intention of that event is the user did something to change the focus status of the application.  When you say that F1 is a menu item shortcut, do you mean it is a shortcut to the same code that is executed when the menu is selected, or that you have it setup as a menu mnemonic?

In the end, shortcut keys do not generally change focus intrinsically, whereas the mouse actions required to click a menu item do, and that is something you may have to account for yourself.

Comment: Yes, its a shortcut to the same code that is executed when the menu is selected

Comment: Then I think you are going to have to account for the logic in focusLost yourself in this case - it comes into play for you with mouse events because the user triggers it when clicking, but when they just use the key strokes there is no focus change.